# search words highlight code not working correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have used a piece of jQuery to highlight the search results, it works nice but i want to match all single words not the whole phrase that i have entered, if i search for "lorem ipsum dolor" it looks for this matching phrase, but i want that the script highlightes all of the single words and not the whole phrase

heres my jQuery code

```
    $("#main-search-input").bind('keyup', function(e){
        var text = $.trim($(this).val());
        if(text !== '' && text !== ' '){
          var pattern = new RegExp(text, "gi");
        }
        $('.sr-results a').each(function(i){
            var str = this;
            var orgText = $(str).text();
                orgText = orgText.replace(pattern, function($1){
                return "<b class='sr-highlight'>" + $1 + "</b>";
            });
         $(str).html(orgText);
        });   
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the string on a space and then build your regex to look like /(word1|word2|word3)/.

```
var pattern = new RegExp('('+$.unique(text.split(" ")).join("|")+')',"gi");
```

Comment: The code that Ryan offers actually doesn't need a loop. It creates a single regex that will match any and all of the words you feed to it; you just need to run that regex instead of the one you used in your code. (Replace your `var pattern...` line with Ryan's.)

Comment: Thanks, if it doesn't needs a loop than we will skip the loop! This works perfect thanks for the quick solution!

Answer (score 0):

Break your search term into words.

```
var words = text.split(' ');
```

Make sure there are not duplicates.

```
$.unique( words );
```

Last you simply do what you're already doing but in loop

```
for ( var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++ ) {
   var word = words[i],
       pattern = new RegExp(word, "gi");
       //and so on
}
```